# Avatar notification listener using smack library for android

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have been trying to have set up a listener which will notify me about my friend changing his avatar image but stuck so for.Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What have you  tried so far?

Comment: I could not find anything actually.I see you can get user avatar image using VCard but how to get notified particularly when they change their avatar.

Comment: Have you ever worked with Smack library? @wmk

Comment: I do not know if you can actually get notified as to when the avatar is changed, however you can change presence of the user after avatar is updated then fetch the avatar when you detect a change in presence.

Comment: ok thanks @kabuto178